# On lower envelope of a map

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $f:X\to\mathbb R$. The lower envelope of $f$ is $g(x)=\sup_n\inf_{y\in B_{1/n}(x)}f(y)$, where $B_\epsilon(x)$ is the ball centered at $x$ with radius $\epsilon$. Does $g$ coincide with the map $h(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf_{y\in B_{1/n}(x)}f(y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. Indeed, let $g_n(x) : = \inf_{y\in B_{1/n}(x)}f(y)$. Then it is easy to see that $g_n(x)\le g_{n+1}(x)$ and hence $$g(x) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} g_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x) = h(x).$$